# Rename a file to the same as the biggest file in a directory

Tags: windows, powershell, batch-file

I have a movie collection setup on my nas and am trying to rename all of my subtitle files to the same name as the movie located in the same directory. For example:

```
D:\Movies\2 Guns (2013) (Bluray)\
-2 Guns (2013).mkv
-English.srt
```

I would like for the english.srt file to be renamed to:

```
2 Guns (2013).srt
```

Long story short, I can't use any type of media manager to accomplish this.  I would love for it to be a batch file, but am willing to use powershell or even a 3rd party program as long as it isn't a media manager of some sort.  I need the name to be generated based off the largest file located in the same directory, not the folder name as some of these do not match the filenames. Also, the .srt files will not always be named english.srt

**EDIT-**

So I came up with this:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /F "delims=" %%A in ('dir /b *.mp4 *.avi *.mkv') do (
set basename="%%~nA"
ren *.srt !basename!.eng.srt
)
```

This works beautifully, but how can I make this recursive so I can run it from parent directory vs one by one?

Comment: You can provide multiple file patterns to `dir`, like: `dir /B *.m* *.avi`. However, your code does not reflect the example above...

Comment: Thank you so much for that!  Too simple and overlooked.  Edited my example and followup question!

Comment: Do not include solutions in the question; rather post them in an answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change `dir /b ...` to  `dir /b /s ...` this will recurse through sub directories.

You may need to include full paths where you do the renaming too.

---

Here's the whole script.

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /F "delims=" %%A in ('dir /b /s *.mp4 *.avi *.mkv') do (
    set basename="%%~nA"
    ren "%%~dpA*.srt" "!basename!.eng.srt"
)
```

Note I made some changes to the `ren` command too.

We wrap the name with quotes incase you have spaces to deal with. And we also use `%%dpA` to clarify which drive and path we want to work from.

Comment: I apologize for the hand holding, but I honestly have no clue what to change. I changed what you proposed for dir command and tried double quotes around both parts of my ren command, but to no avail.  I just barely figured out how to handle spaces in filenames via delims.

Comment: I've edited the script. See if that works. If not then can you run 'dir /b/s' from the parent directory and post the results.

Comment: Ok, that worked beautifully!  Thank you so much!  Thank you for explaining to me what you changed.  I was only missing %%~dpA when I commented.  That portion is what I am need to learn more about!  Thank you again and back to reading more for me!

Comment: Golden rule: Always have echo on. Here's a reference for the various ~ operators. https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Windows_Batch_Scripting